# How to store image on database using Php MySql in iOS

Tags: php, mysql

I am making one web services part for the app in which i need to store images on database. I have stored name, message and some other information successfully, however for storing images i have used blob, but still what function i need to write for saving.

Comment: Why store files in an RDBMS and not in that database that has been optimised for file storage and retrieval, your *filesystem*?

Comment: what have you tried? There are many source code available for same. Have you searched for it?

Comment: Hi Prateek i have searched, however didn't got anything good for iPhone,like i always send images from iPhone in NSData format, so what  query do we have to write for accepting that images.

Comment: Below are the steps i have used for storing name,email and password, however not sure about how to work with image                              mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die('Unable to find Database');

$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

$query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES('','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Could not connect');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to store an image in the database is by creating a binary large object column (BLOB) in the table. And then store

```
<?php
$dbh = mysql_connect("localhost", "user");
mysql_select_db("test");
$data = file_get_contents($image_filename);
// This is important to avoid a ' to accidentally close a string
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO testblob(data) VALUES ('$data')");
?>
```

Comment: Below are the steps i have used for storing name,email and password, however not sure about how to work with image                              mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die('Unable to find Database');

$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

$query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES('','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Could not connect');

Answer (score 0):

What size are the images you want to store ? I think BLOB's max is 64kb. You may need to use a MEDIUMBLOB column type.

Comment: Below are the steps i have used for storing name,email and password, however not sure about how to work with image                              mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die('Unable to find Database');

$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

$query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES('','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Could not connect');

Comment: You should secure your $_GET variable before operating any MySQL Query with its content.

Comment: Yes all values will be send from iPhone app and it is working perfectly.

Comment: No, what Ki Jey meant is that everything passed in from the client side (such as all values in `$_GET`) should be escaped using `mysql_real_escape_string` or equivalent.